# Azure SQL Data Warehouse CTAS statistics

Tags: azure-synapse

Does the "Create table as" function in SQL Data Warehouse create statistics in the background, or do they have to manually be created (as I would when I do a normal "Create table" statement?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the current version, you **always** have to create column-level statistics on tables, irrespective of whether it was created with a normal `CREATE TABLE` or the CTAS `CREATE TABLE AS...` command.  It's also good practice to create stats for columns used in JOINs, WHERE clauses, GROUP BY, ORDER BY and DISTINCT clauses.

Regarding tables created with CTAS, the database engine has a correct idea of how many rows are in the table as listed in `sys.partitions`, but not at the column-level statistics level.  For tables created by `CREATE TABLE` this defaults to 1,000 rows.  For the example below, the first table was created with a CTAS and has 208 rows, the second table with an ordinary `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` from the first table and also has 208 rows, but `sys.partitions` believes it to have 1,000 eg

[image: sys.partitions]

Creating any column-level statistics manually will correct this number.

In summary, always manually create statistics against important columns irrespective of how the table was created.